# Powershell Move Item in bulk fail

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to rename file based on pattern and then move them to a new folder

```
$ltmpPath = "D:somepath\Temp\"

$ldstPath = "D:\OtherPath\Folder\"

get-childItem $ltmpPath | rename-item -newname { $_.name -replace "(^[a-z]+)(\d\d\d\d)\.pdf", "sg`${2}14.pdf"
get-childItem $ltmpPath | Where-Object { $_.name -match "(^sg)(\d\d\d\d\d\d)\.pdf"} | move-item -Destination $ldstPath -WhatIf
```

All it does is copying every file to a file D:\OtherPath\Folder instead of D:\OtherPath\Folder\sgxxxxxx.pdf.

What if: Performing the operation "Move File" on target "Item: D:somepath\Temp\sg311014.pdf Destination: D:\OtherPath\Folder\".

Comment: I don't understand the question, could you rewrite it?

Comment: hope this is more clear.

Comment: I created 2 folders on my local, added some pdf files and ran your commands, I got back the following:
What if: Performing the operation "Move File" on target "Item: C:\temp\new\as - Copy (2).pdf Destination: C:\temp\new1\as - Copy (2).pdf".
What if: Performing the operation "Move File" on target "Item: C:\temp\new\as - Copy (3).pdf Destination: C:\temp\new1\as - Copy (3).pdf".
etc..
Maybe it's something to do with the regex you are using

Comment: ThanksI'm on Windows 10 so maybe that's the issues I will try it on another Computer